# Kafka Spring Cloud Stream Batch Consumption - Unable to cast class to Message

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

Facing below error message while consuming KafkAvroSerialized messages in Spring Cloud Stream batch mode. This was earlier working fine in non-batch mode.

Below are the only two changes made to convert existing application to batch mode -

1. In application.yml enabled property batch-mode:true 2) modified argument to List<Message<SpecificRecord>> which was previously Message<SpecificRecord>

   `Error Message : org.springframework.messaging.MessageException: Exception thrown while invoking MyConsumer#consume[1 args]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: SomeClass cannot be cast to org.springframework.messaging.Message`

Please help in resolving the issue.

Comment: Difference I have noticed is previously in non-batch mode I used to receive GenericMessage with kafka headers but in batch-mode I am directly receiving Payload without Kafka headers

Comment: I see that @StreamListener does not work with batch-mode. I am referencing to example mentioned over here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/892. However, I am not sure how Spring knows which method to invoke in case of multiple binders consuming from multiple topics in same application.

Comment: I am able to receive messages using @StreamListener . But only problem I am facing is I am losing Kafka headers. I am directly getting the payload not GenericMessage any more.

Comment: I am facing similar issue , did your solution work ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67565589/batch-processing-with-manual-acknowledgment-using-spring-cloud-stream-kafka

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to get the headers in batch-mode but they were wrapped in List.

If you need to access metadata and other headers, you cannot use @StreamListener, you will need to write your consumer function using the functional programming method, such as:

```
@Bean
Consumer<Message<List<String>>> input() {
    return list -> {
        System.out.println(list);
    };
}
```

and add spring.cloud.function.definition=input(your function name), also set the binding to input(your function name) -in-0 such as

```
spring:
  profiles: dev
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: input
      bindings:
        input-in-0:
          destination: yourDestination
          group: yourGroup
```

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_functional_binding_names

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/multi/multi__programming_model.html

Answer (score 0):

I too am able to get to the point where in I can get this following block working,

```
@Bean
Consumer<Message<List<Foo>>> consumer() {
    return  message -> {
        log.info("Message={}", message);
        message.getPayload().forEach(event -> {
            log.info("event = {}", event);
        });
        message.getHeaders().entrySet().forEach(header -> {
            log.info("header = {}", header);
        });
    };
}
```

But, what I ultimately have is two lists, one List and another List, and is there a way to pair Foo - Headers, reliably?